# Arduino Due, program not there after power off

Tags: power, arduino-due, reset

When i program my arduino Due after a RESET, my program is still there.
However, when i power off my Due and then turn it back on, no program is there!

There is no persistence in the program and i have to program it all again!
I am programming it throught the Programming port.

EDIT: If it doesn't boot properly with my code and then i press the RESET button, then my code is loaded and it works like i programmed it. But how can i make it so that it works straight away, after it's fed with power?